Why my test on using regex to determine the prime number fails?
I was learning regex, and i got to know that regex can determine whether the number of 1s in a string of all 1s is a prime number (e.g. 111 has 3 1s and 3 is a prime number while 1111 has 4 1s and 4 is not a prime number), the regex is as follow:
/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/

At First, i thought the '/' on the start and the end was useless, so i ignored it and made a test on my bash terminal, and got the wrong result unless i added the '/' on each side of the pattern.
i have read the grep manual and searched for google, but none of them solve the puzzle.
Below are the contrast test that i did
my test on bash
i tested a string of 17 1s（the prime number), only with the ‘/’ version that i get the correct result(Nothing print out), BUT then i found out that for every test number, if i add the '/', it would not print anything even if the number is not a prime. On the other hand, without adding '/', it would print the number even if the number is a prime num.
i am not a native English speaker, if there are some mistakes in my sentences, please forgive me.
if you can help me or give me some ideas , i would be very grateful.

The / characters are not part of the regular expression. Some languages use / as delimiters around regular expressions, but they're not actually part of the expression itself. egrep doesn't use / delimiters, so if you're using it you shouldn't put /es around the expression. But egrep doesn't support the +? operator, so this won't work with it anyway. See "Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?"

@GordonDavisson Thanks you so much! i check on wiki that says"Modern regular expression tools allow a quantifier to be specified as non-greedy, by putting a question mark after the quantifier:([[.*?]])" , but i  did not check the grep manual for the greedy part,  which does not exist indeed. Again, Thanks for your comment!

"Modern" is meaningless. Different tools support different regexp flavors, that is all. The 3 mandatory POSIX (i.e. available on all Unix systems) tools that use regexps are grep, sed, and awk. grep and sed support Basic Regular Expressions (BREs) by default, grep -E and sed -E (where -E supported) and awk support Extended Regular Expressions (EREs), grep -P and perl and some other tools support Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCREs) with the latter being where that "add a ?" stuff applies, it's undefined behavior in BREs/EREs whether the tool is modern or not.

I correct the Pattern and i finally get the correct result!
egrep pattern does not support the greedy strategy, but i guess it would only affect the  performance rather than the correctness, so i delete it and get the result i want.
small test
By the way, the wikibooks say
\n  Matches what the nth marked subexpression matched, where n is a digit from 1 to 9. This construct is theoretically irregular and **was not adopted in the POSIX ERE syntax**. Some tools allow referencing more than nine capturing groups.

but the manual of grep does notes that it support BACK REFERENCE AND SUBExpression

BREs (and, I think, PCREs) support backreferences and subexpressions, EREs do not. You have to learn the difference between BREs, EREs, and PCREs along with which variants (e.g. GNU or BSD) of which tools (e.g. grep, sed, awk, perl) with which options (e.g. -E or -P) support which regexp variety to really understand regular expressions.

Please don't post images or links in questions or answers unless you NEED an image to show different colors or something that can't be shown with regular text. Just put text in your Q&A. I see in your image you're calling egrep - egrep has been obsolete for about a quarter of a century in favor of grep -E and you should not expect all greps to support backreferences when called with -E as that's undefined behavior. To avoid undefined behavior you should be using a BRE, e.g. grep '^\(11\{1,\}\)\1\{1,\}$'. See See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html.

@EdMorton Thanks! it is obvious that i still got a lot of things to learn:)
